# Buttons not underlined in Xcode but underlined on iPhone

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have made an app with buttons. The buttons aren't underlined in Xcode. However, if I run this app on my iPhone, the buttons are suddenly underlined. How do I prevent buttons from being underlined?

Comment: It's probably due to one of the accessibility settings you have enabled on your iPhone. Do you have "Button Shapes" enabled on your iPhone?

Comment: Oh thank you very much :))

Answer (score 0):

Just bumped into the same problem, but for those who do not know how to enable "Button Shapes"

1. Launch the Settings app on your iPhone or iPad.
2. Tap on General.
3. Tap on Accessibility.
4. Turn On the option for Button Shapes — it's about half way down the page.

You are welcome!

[image]